# css on different input classes

Tags: html, css, class, error-handling, settings

hello i have the following problem:

i do check my form for some php error messages.

in case of no error i simply have my css setting:

```css
.wrapper #frame form fieldset ul input {
    color: #f23;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline:none;
}
```

and my focus settings:

```css
.wrapper #frame form fieldset ul input:focus{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

okay, now i changed this line:

```
<input type="text" id="normal" name="1" value=""/>
```

with adding the class of error:

```
<input class="err" type="text" id="normal" name="1" value=""/>
```

the problem is that my settings just take place for my class details on the input fields but not on my focus settings:

```css
.err {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    outline:none;   
    background-image: url(../images/error.png);
}
.err input:focus{
    color:#f23;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #f23;
}
```

so if there is someone who could tell me why this does not work i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a class of `error` in your HTML, and in your CSS you've set the class to `err`; if you use the same name consistently (whichever you choose) it should work.

Your *current* HTML:

```
<input class="error" type="text" id="normal" name="1" value=""/>
```

...and CSS:

```
.err {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    outline:none;   
    background-image: url(../images/error.png);
}
.err input:focus{
    color:#f23;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #f23;
}
```

Also, in your CSS you're selecting an `input` that's a descendant of an element with the `err` class-name, not an `input` element *with* that class-name. So, altogether you should use something like:

```
<input class="err" type="text" id="normal" name="1" value=""/>

input.err {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    outline:none;   
    background-image: url(../images/error.png);
}
input.err:focus{
    color:#f23;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #f23;
}
```